# If you cast True Polymorph on a party member to turn them into a monster, will they turn hostile or remain loyal?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph

If you cast *true polymorph* on a party member to transform them into, let's say, an intellect devourer, is he now going to attempt to go after the wizard for his intellect? Or would he remain allied to the party and only go after enemies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quote you're looking for in the description of [*true polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph) is:

> ***Creature into Creature.*** If you turn a creature into another kind of creature, the new form can be any kind you choose whose challenge rating is equal to or less than the target's (or its level, if the target doesn't have a challenge rating). The target's game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the new form. **It retains its alignment and personality**.

Turning into an intellect devourer won't make your fellow party member any more interested in eating the wizard's brains than they were previously.

Comment: Well, depending on how annoyed he is by being transformed. If someone permanently turned me into a monster, I wouldn't be too happy about it.

Comment: @Miniman and if you were an intellect devourer you could readily express those feelings.